# Как не выводить товары цена которых больше 500 000

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

код вывода товаров рабочий . Получил регулярную цену (с ней проблемы) , объявил максимальную цену , сделал проверку и не работает ... Что только не пробовал , гугл не помог ((

```
function disel_generators_credit_shortcode() {
$regular_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price' , true);
$max_price = 500000;    

if($regular_price <= $max_price){ 

    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'product_cat' => 'dizelnye',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => '64',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_stock_status',
            'value' => 'instock',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);

  $loop = new WP_Query($args);


  while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

  global $product, $woocommerce;

  include 'tpls/credit-products-loop.php';

  endwhile;

  }

}

add_shortcode('credit_disel' , 'disel_generators_credit_shortcode');
```

Comment: а можете показать, что Вам выдаст `var_dump($regular_price);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  global $product, $woocommerce;

  $price = $product->get_regular_price();

  if ($price <= $max_price) {
   include 'tpls/credit-products-loop.php';
  }

  endwhile;
```